# Hyperlink label is not working with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, linklabel

I have to create tap on link from `label` ,so I found this link **https://github.com/d6u/TapLabel**.When I create demo ,it's working on `View` and `tableview`. But when I use this **TapLabel example** in my project ,it's not working. Actually I need tap link in my **chat view** , my view is look like a **messenger**. Here is my code. The `delegate` method is not working.

**This is my cell with taplabel delegate method**

```
class BHBMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    let headerImgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    // let contentImgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()


    //let contentLbl:UILabel = UILabel()
    let contentLbl = TapLabel()

    let bubbleImgView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var delegate: AppDelegate!
    let aDataBase : databaseinit = databaseinit()
    var message:BHBMessage?{//Construction of cell layout model based on message

        didSet{
            delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            self.headerImgView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.contentLbl.removeFromSuperview()
            self.bubbleImgView.removeFromSuperview()

            self.contentView.addSubview(self.headerImgView)
            self.contentView.addSubview(self.bubbleImgView)

            self.contentLbl.font = UIFont (name: "Arial", size: 14)


            self.headerImgView.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0
            self.headerImgView.layer.masksToBounds = true

            self.contentLbl.delegate = self;









            //he data message to the model head , content, bubble view

            if(message?.role == Role.Sender)
            {
                //**************** Actually this is sender from Database
                // Yaha par ulta hai 
                // this is change right to left
                if(self.delegate.MyImage != nil)
                {
                    self.headerImgView.image = self.delegate.MyImage
                }else
                {
                    self.headerImgView.image = UIImage(named: "User-yellow-icon.png")
                }
            }else
            {
                //**************** Actually this is Receiver  from Database

                if(self.delegate.FrontImage != nil)
                {
                    self.headerImgView.image = self.delegate.FrontImage
                }else
                {
                    self.headerImgView.image = UIImage(named: "User-yellow-icon.png")
                }

            }

           // self.headerImgView.image = message?.role == Role.Sender ? UIImage(named: "icon01") : self.delegate.FrontImage

            self.bubbleImgView.image = message?.role != Role.Receive ? UIImage(named: "chatto_bg_normal") : UIImage(named: "chatfrom_bg_normal")


            let str:String! = message?.content


            let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [
                NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12),
                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: {
                    let p = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                    p.lineSpacing = 5
                    p.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                    return p
                    }()
                ])

            var splitStringArray = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")




            for var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.count ; i++
            {
                let word:String = splitStringArray[i];

                if word.hasPrefix("www") || word.hasPrefix("http")
                {

                    let range: Range<String.Index> = (str.rangeOfString(word)!)
                    let start:Int = Int("\(range.startIndex)")!
                    let end:Int = word.characters.count
                   // print(start)
                    text.addAttribute(TapLabel.LinkContentName, value: word, range: NSMakeRange(start, end))
                    text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), range: NSMakeRange(start, end))
                    text.addAttribute(TapLabel.SelectedForegroudColorName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(start, end))






                }

            }


            self.contentLbl.attributedText = text
            self.contentLbl.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping


            self.contentLbl.sizeToFit()



            self.bubbleImgView.addSubview(self.contentLbl)// Add label
         self.contentLbl.delegate = self



            self.headerImgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.contentLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.bubbleImgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


            self.contentLbl.textAlignment = message?.role != Role.Receive ? NSTextAlignment.Right : NSTextAlignment.Left
            self.contentLbl.numberOfLines = 0

            var viewsDictionary : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                 viewsDictionary = ["header": self.headerImgView, "content": self.contentLbl, "bubble": self.bubbleImgView]




            var header_constraint_H_Format = ""
            var header_constraint_V_Format = ""
            var bubble_constraint_H_Format = ""
            var bubble_constraint_V_Format = ""
            var content_constraint_H_Format = ""
            var content_constraint_V_Format = ""


            if message?.role == Role.Sender {
                header_constraint_H_Format =  "[header(50)]-5-|"
                header_constraint_V_Format =  "V:|-5-[header(50)]"
                bubble_constraint_H_Format  =  "|-(>=5)-[bubble]-10-[header]"
                bubble_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|-5-[bubble(>=50)]-5-|"
                content_constraint_H_Format  =  "|-(>=5)-[content]-25-|"
                content_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|[content]-5-|"
            } else {
                header_constraint_H_Format =  "|-5-[header(50)]"
                header_constraint_V_Format =  "V:|-5-[header(50)]"
                bubble_constraint_H_Format  =  "[header]-10-[bubble]-(>=5)-|"
                bubble_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|-5-[bubble(>=50)]-5-|"
                content_constraint_H_Format  =  "|-25-[content]-(>=5)-|"
                content_constraint_V_Format  =  "V:|[content]-5-|"
            }


            let header_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(header_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
            let header_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(header_constraint_V_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

            let bubble_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(bubble_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
            let bubble_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(bubble_constraint_V_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

            let content_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(content_constraint_H_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
            let content_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(content_constraint_V_Format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

            self.contentView.addConstraints(header_constraint_H as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
            self.contentView.addConstraints(header_constraint_V as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
            self.contentView.addConstraints(bubble_constraint_H as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
            self.contentView.addConstraints(bubble_constraint_V as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
            self.bubbleImgView.addConstraints(content_constraint_H as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
            self.bubbleImgView.addConstraints(content_constraint_V as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
        }
    }

}

extension BHBMessageCell : TapLabelDelegate
{
    func tapLabel(tapLabel: TapLabel, didSelectLink link: String) {
        print(link)
    }
}
```

**Here is my view tableview cell **

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let getMessage:String! = self.messages[indexPath.row].content as String

            let longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "cellLongPressed:")
            longPress.delegate = self
            longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1
            longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1


            // print(self.messages[indexPath.row].msg_images)

            let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BHBMessageCell") as! BHBMessageCell

           cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)


             cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            cell.message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            return cell
    }
```

[image]

I have add the link of image which shows in **blue color** but when i try to click on image then it does not click and also not call the `delegate` method but when i create the demo then it works fine.

Comment: What do you mean the delegate method isn't working? Is it being called (have you set a breakpoint or placed a log statement inside it) or just not doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: yes u have set breakpoint but its not working , i have create clickable label name is ** contentLbl** but in my tableview didSet method is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have a line in your first code block that declares `var delegate...`. Did you mean to set `self.delegate = ...`? It's odd for a delegate to be a variable scoped only to a method rather than as a property of the class.

Comment: Please describe some more i cant able to understand , i have set delegate 
self.contentLbl.delegate = self